# Roll two dice. What is the probability that one die shows exactly two more than the other die?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> Two fair six-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that one die shows exactly two more than the other die (for example, rolling a $1$ and $3$, or rolling a $6$ and a $4$)?

I know how to calculate the probabilities of each event by itself, but I do not know how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: All you need to do is compute them separately, and use the probabilistic meaning of "or" and "and."

Comment: The part that throws me off is the "exactly two more than the other die"

Comment: That means they show 1 and 3, or 2 and 4, or 3 and 5, or 4 and 6.

Comment: Just count cases to handle that. Then multiply two to handle the fact that the dice are independent.

Comment: You know that standard six-sided dice have six faces, each with a number (or number of pips) being one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  You have $4$ is exactly two more than $2$, so one die showing $4$ while the other die showing $2$ is allowed.  Similarly, $5$ is exactly two more than $3$, so one die showing $5$ and the other a $3$ is allowed.  $5$ is not exactly two more than $1$ however, so $5$ for one die and $1$ for the other is *not* allowed.

Comment: Possible rolls: $\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(6,4)\}$

Comment: @J.Doe: the reason problems like this use phrases like "exactly two more", is because in everyday English the phrase "two more" can sometimes be ambiguous between "exactly two more" or "at least two more". So for example if someone asks the question, "do you have two more glasses than guests, in case of breakages?", and in fact you have three more glasses than guests, one would not normally answer "no". If asked, "do you have *exactly* two more glasses than guests?", then you'd answer "no".

Comment: The lazy answer is, of course, http://anydice.com/program/7ffc

Comment: Now extend the question to getting exactly 2 greater HitPoints from some mega-sided D&D  die   :-)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To get yourself started, you could draw a table. The rows could be one roll, and the columns could be the other roll. Then the checkmark shows where the rolls are "two away" from each other.

\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c|c|c}
&1&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline
1&&&\checkmark&&&\\\hline
2&&&&\checkmark&&\\\hline
3&\checkmark&&&&\checkmark&\\\hline
4&&\checkmark&&&&\checkmark\\\hline
5&&&\checkmark&&&\\\hline
6&&&&\checkmark&&
\end{array}
Notice that, since all pairs are equally likely, we have a $8/36 = 2/9$ chance of being "two away".

Comment: Very nice graph!  This was exactly the way I was going to explain it. "When in doubt, just do an exhaustive count of all the possible solutions."

Comment: Especially if you "don't know how to start". Thanks.

Comment: By the way, where should I look for a guide to creating similar tables?

Comment: @AntonSherwood I knew $\LaTeX$ before using MSE. MSE uses Mathjax formatting, but is compatible with $\LaTeX$. In particular, I knew how to use the `\array` environment. You can find a sample [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5044/290196), on the MSE meta quick reference to MathJax page.

Comment: Side remark: _MSE_ is usually understood to mean [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) in the “SE universe”, while this side would be called Math.SE or similar.

Comment: Shouldn't you count (1,1) , (2,2) etc twice, giving you 8/42=4/21?

Comment: You could count how many outcomes you have where one die is two larger than the other, these are (without considering the ordering): (1,3), (2,4), (3,5), and (4,6), i.e. 4 positive outcomes.
The total number of outcomes is: (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,5), (5,6) and (6,6), which is a total of 21 outcomes, so 4/21. I know it is probably wrong since everybody else gave 4/18, but why?

Comment: @user consider that (1,2) and (2,1) are distinct outcomes.

Comment: Why are (1,3) and (2,4) pairing missing from this chart?

Comment: @casey Exactly what I am saying, so should be (1,1), (2,2), etc.

Comment: @user You didn't account for them in your counting. It's why you didn't get 8 positives and 36 total. (1,3) and (3,1) are 2 positive outcomes but you incorrectly counted them as the same outcome. It may be easier to see if you imagine the dice are different colors.

Comment: @AntonSherwood  quick "cheat" : when you see some interesting formatting in an answer,  click "edit" to see the source code.

Comment: +1 for the chart, which should make it perfectly clear to anyone.

Comment: @casey you still don't understand what I am saying. If (1,3) is different from (3,1), so should be (1,1) and (1,1), then you have 8 out of 42. Why not? That is my question.

Comment: @user  There is only one distinct ordered pair (1,1), while (1,3) & (3,1) are different. Per Casey, pretend one die is red and the other white, and our ordered pairs are in (r, w) format.
There are six equally-probable outcomes for each die, and the events are independent, making 36 also-equally-probable outcomes for the two dice.  Red 1 and white 3 is different from red 3 and white 1, making two ways to roll {1,3} (unordered pair) but red1 and white 1, aka {1,1}, can only be done one way.

With two dice of the same color, we can't tell by sight (1,3) from (3,1), but we know they both exist.

Comment: @casey MontyHarder Ok, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Anton If you just want to copy the Latex, for playing around with later: right click, then Show Math As, then TeX commands. If there is a very long answer, this is particularly useful for getting the snippet of Latex that you want.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that the question does not ask for distinct outcomes. The OP asked for the probability of the event where one of the dice (either die, i.e. unordered) is exactly two more than the other die. @user's comment listing the possible outcomes is correct, and should be posted as the answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I did that, but one sample doesn't tell me what variations are possible!

Comment: @probablyme, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 20):

Total possible results: $6\times6=36$

Favorable results: $1-3,2-4,3-5,4-6$ and opposites, $8$.

Then the probability is $8/36=2/9$.

Answer (score 10):

The probability of rolling a 1 and 3 is 1/18. Same for the probability of 2&4, 3&5, and 4&6.

So the overall probability of the dice being two apart equals 4/18 = 2/9.

Answer (score 7):

Any result will do as long as the other die can score the same number plus two, that gets us with n-2 per die (n being number of sides). This gets us 2(n-2) posible results over n^2 (as we have two identical dice)

then the probability is: 2(n-2)/n^2

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, I counted eight.
[image: Dice image courtesy of Google[1]]

Answer (score 4):

Could use the multiplication rule:

The probability of Die 1 landing on 1-4 is 4/6.
The probability of the Die 2 landing on the number that's Die1+2 is then 1/6.

(4/6) * (1/6) = 4/36

We multiply this by 2 to account the scenario where Die 2 is the 1-4 die, and then Die 1 is two higher than Die 2. So, 8/36.

Answer (score 2):

If the first die is 1, the other can only be 3, probability = 1/6

If the first die is 2, the other can only be 4, probability = 1/6

If the first die is 5, the other can only be 3, probability = 1/6

If the first die is 6, the other can only be 4, probability = 1/6

If the first die is 3, the other can only be 1 or 5, probability = 2/6

If the first die is 4, the other can only be 2 or 6, probability = 2/6

Total probability is (1+1+1+1+2+2)/(6+6+6+6+6+6) = 8/36 = 2/9

Comment: Sorry but 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 + 2/6 + 2/6 = 4/3, not 2/9.

Comment: @Did You are absolutely right, I corrected it with what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: But now the ratio by (6+6+6+6+6+6) is an even greater mystery. Where does it come from?

Comment: Not a mistery, (6+6+6+6+6+6)  is the sum of all the possible outcomes.

Comment: Then none of the preceding computations is relevant. If one wants to count cases, then one should count cases from the start, not jump from probabilities to numbers of cases.

Comment: For the case when die 1 is 1, you have 6 total outcomes and one positive outcome, and so on. Add them up and you get 8/36. I don't understand what you are saying. I am not adding the probability, I am adding the outcomes. Maybe I was misleading because I wrote probability = 1/6? What is meant is 1 positive case out of 6, and so on.